# Running `?%ls` in jupyterlab shows Repr: <alias ls for 'dir /on'>, what is 'dir /on'?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Just curious about why this output is given, for other magic commands, appending `?` gives a docstring, e.g. `?%pwd` shows:

```
Return the current working directory path.

Examples
--------
::

  In [9]: pwd
  Out[9]: '/home/nuser/sprint/ipython'
File:      c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\magics\osm.py
```

Why does Running `?%ls` in show `Repr: <alias ls for 'dir /on'>` and what does that mean? Not sure what `Repr` is or what `dir /on` is.

Comment: You're on Windows, and `dir /on` is a Windows command prompt command. See its docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir

Answer (score 0):

'%ls' uses the default alias defined in [alias.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/0e4d6390b2174fb1b352a082b72ad387ae696e87/IPython/core/alias.py) which on a windows system is set to 'dir /on'. As already commented by "user2357112 supports Monica" this is the Windows command [dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) (with the options to sort the output files and directories alphabetically by name).

%pwd, in contrast, actually has a python line_magic implementation given in [osm.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/652328801e4c3860696d275aba38a4838000e2f6/IPython/core/magics/osm.py) as the output you obtained shows.